# What is the earliest hook to modify post content?

Tags: filters, the-content

I have installed a plugin that adds stuff at the end of the content.  I just want to apply my modifications to the post content before this plugin does.

In my case or otherwise, what is the earliest hook that can be used to modify post content even before `the_content` filters are applied?

Comment: what priority does it hook `the_content` on? you can use the same hook and just change priority to control whether yours runs before or after.

Comment: @Milo, thanks for replying, No it doesn't use priority. I tried priority 0,1,-1,etc... in my plugin and no response . . ..

Comment: as you can see on the [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) codex page, default priority is 20 if it's not specified. anything lower than 20 should run earlier, but you haven't shown us the code you have tried.

Comment: @Milo, I guess you meant 10 not 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two or more filters are hooked to the same filter hook, the conflict is resolved as follows:

1. If the filters are hooked with a `priority` parameter, the filter with a lowest value for the priority will be executed first. If no priority value is supplied, the default value is taken as 10.
2. If two or more filters are hooked with the same priority, the filter that was hooked first will take priority.

Eg.

```
add_filter('the_content','filter_1',5);
add_filter('the_content','filter_2');
add_filter('the_content','filter_3');
add_filter('the_content','filter_4',1);
```

In the above example, `filter_4()` will be called first, followed by `filter_1()`. `filter_2()` and `filter_3()` have same priority ie. 10. Hence, `filter_2()` will be called next because sequentially, `filter_2()` was added before `filter_3()`. And of course, finally `filter_3` is called.

Reference: [Wordpress Codex Page.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)